Graph theory game where person aims at getting from begin node to end node and clicks on nodes they are standing on to rearrange edges
I am looking for the following graph theory game. It works as follows:
In the game, at each level, nodes are presented. A person stands at each moment on top of one of these nodes.
There are edges. The person is in control of two operations:

they may cross an edge to get to the other node

they may click on the node they are standing on. When the node is clicked, all edges in the graph rearrange themselves (like matchsticks disconnected from their glued-to-the-table endpoints, acted upon by drops of water). Thus, when the person clicks on the node they are standing on, each edge in the graph, reattaches to none, one new, or two new, nodes, and the graph thus changes. The person may then cross the edges that are attached to the node they are standing on to get to other nodes.


The way the edges rearrange themselves when the person clicks on the node they are standing on depends on the node they are standing on. The edges move, but the nodes don't move. The person may scroll to view how far they are from the destination node. It could be convenient to make the graph(s) planar (the edges don't cross, for visual purposes).
The aim of the game is to get from the beginning node to the destination node.
Where can I find such a game.
Has anyone implemented, such thing?
Thank you for your pointers and implementations.
